# dumping csv file data into db through sql query

Tags: php, mysql, csv, command

i have a .csv file containing a table data.I want to dump the total csv file into db using a query in mysql using column name as key...

rather than doing it manually...like using "insert into" query...

if any other language like php or python program make this work...then also ok..

can some one suggest me....pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this fairly easily with navicat software.
[more info here](http://www.navicat.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[load data local infile ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/your_file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table;

You need to ensure the mysql user has enough privileges to perform `load`

Comment: Check out the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` options in case you need them.

Comment: can you suggest me to execute an php file that automatically uploads the csv file into db....like an interface....

Comment: @PRINCE EMMIT - there is not so straightforward, maybe you can ask another question

Comment: i have made a file in php..<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('databasename',$con)or die(mysql_error());
$file_handle = fopen("your_file.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
$import="INSERT into table("","","","")values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]');if(mysql_query($import))
{echo "Database created";}
else{echo "Error creating database:".mysql_error();
echo "error in prim_key".$data[0];}}
fclose($file_handle);
mysql_close($con);?> :(

Comment: please ask another question, don't you think the comment section is squeeze for this?